# Error with compiling dlib to Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cmake, x11, dlib

I had compiled dlib to Xcode with reference the site of "http://prabhu.xyz/2017/05/29/getting-started-with-dlib-on-ios.html"
I followed the steps just like the site has mentioned, but I received the error messages: https://github.com/hsmlee/dlip-error/blob/master/README.md

I have tried to find the reason why I received the error messages.
I guess it means that I need to install X11.

So, I had installed X11.

cmake -G Xcode .. -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/X11/include

cmake --build . --config Release

I built by above the steps, but I received the error messages same as previous one.

You can check the following error sentences.

Please, give me the great feedback!

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
“_XwcDrawString”, referenced from:
void nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::vals_internal::create<unsigned int>(unsigned int*, int, bool, bool, bool, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type)::inner::XDrawString(_XDisplay*, unsigned long, _XOC*, _XGC*, int, int, wchar_t*, int) in libdlib.a(fonts.o)
“_XAllocColor”, referenced from:
nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::vals_internal::rgb2color(nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type, _XDisplay*, unsigned long&) in libdlib.a(fonts.o)
“_XQueryColor”, referenced from:
nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::vals_internal::color2rgb(unsigned long, _XDisplay*, unsigned long&) in libdlib.a(fonts.o)
“_XExtentsOfFontSet”, referenced from:
void nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::vals_internal::create<unsigned int>(unsigned int*, int, bool, bool, bool, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type) in libdlib.a(fonts.o)
“_XSetBackground”, referenced from:
void nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::vals_internal::create<unsigned int>(unsigned int*, int, bool, bool, bool, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type) in libdlib.a(fonts.o)
“_XGetImage”, referenced from:
void nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::vals_internal::create<unsigned int>(unsigned int*, int, bool, bool, bool, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type) in libdlib.a(fonts.o)
“_XPutBackEvent”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::~event_handler_thread() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XInitThreads”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::thread() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XClearArea”, referenced from:
dlib::base_window::invalidate_rectangle(dlib::rectangle const&) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XTranslateCoordinates”, referenced from:
dlib::base_window::get_pos(long&, long&) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XUnmapWindow”, referenced from:
dlib::base_window::hide() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XSetWMName”, referenced from:
dlib::base_window::set_title(std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> > const&) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XDestroyIC”, referenced from:
dlib::base_window::~base_window() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XCloseDisplay”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::~event_handler_thread() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::vals_internal::~vals_internal() in libdlib.a(fonts.o)
“_XFreeFontSet”, referenced from:
dlib::base_window::~base_window() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
void nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::vals_internal::create<unsigned int>(unsigned int*, int, bool, bool, bool, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type) in libdlib.a(fonts.o)
nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::vals_internal::~vals_internal() in libdlib.a(fonts.o)
“_XwcTextExtents”, referenced from:
void nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::vals_internal::create<unsigned int>(unsigned int*, int, bool, bool, bool, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type)::inner::XTextExtents(_XOC*, wchar_t*, int, XRectangle*, XRectangle*) in libdlib.a(fonts.o)
“_XDefaultDepth”, referenced from:
void nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::vals_internal::create<unsigned int>(unsigned int*, int, bool, bool, bool, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type) in libdlib.a(fonts.o)
“_XVaCreateNestedList”, referenced from:
dlib::base_window::base_window(bool, bool) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
dlib::base_window::set_im_pos(long, long) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XFreeStringList”, referenced from:
dlib::base_window::base_window(bool, bool) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
void nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::vals_internal::create<unsigned int>(unsigned int*, int, bool, bool, bool, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type) in libdlib.a(fonts.o)
“_XwcTextListToTextProperty”, referenced from:
dlib::base_window::set_title(std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> > const&) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XSelectInput”, referenced from:
dlib::base_window::base_window(bool, bool) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XFillRectangle”, referenced from:
void nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::vals_internal::create<unsigned int>(unsigned int*, int, bool, bool, bool, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type) in libdlib.a(fonts.o)
“_XSetWMProtocols”, referenced from:
dlib::base_window::base_window(bool, bool) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XCloseIM”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::~event_handler_thread() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XMapRaised”, referenced from:
dlib::base_window::show() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XPeekIfEvent”, referenced from:
dlib::get_from_clipboard(std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> >&) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XwcFreeStringList”, referenced from:
dlib::get_from_clipboard(std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> >&) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XConvertSelection”, referenced from:
dlib::get_from_clipboard(std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> >&) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XOpenDisplay”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::thread() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
void nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::vals_internal::create<unsigned int>(unsigned int*, int, bool, bool, bool, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type) in libdlib.a(fonts.o)
“_dgesvd_“, referenced from:
dlib::lapack::binding::gesvd(char, char, int, int, double*, int, double*, double*, int, double*, int, double*, int) in libdlib.a(global_function_search.o)
“_XFreeModifiermap”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::init_keyboard_mod_masks() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_cblas_sgemm”, referenced from:
dlib::blas_bindings::cblas_gemm(dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_ORDER, dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_TRANSPOSE, dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_TRANSPOSE, int, int, int, float, float const*, int, float const*, int, float, float*, int) in libdlib.a(cpu_dlib.o)
dlib::blas_bindings::cblas_gemm(dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_ORDER, dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_TRANSPOSE, dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_TRANSPOSE, int, int, int, float, float const*, int, float const*, int, float, float*, int) in libdlib.a(tensor_tools.o)
“_XNextEvent”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::event_handler() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XGetWindowProperty”, referenced from:
dlib::get_from_clipboard(std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> >&) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XSetNormalHints”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::event_handler() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
dlib::base_window::base_window(bool, bool) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
dlib::base_window::set_size(int, int) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XGetIMValues”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::thread() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XkbKeycodeToKeysym”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::init_keyboard_mod_masks() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XResizeWindow”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::event_handler() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
dlib::base_window::set_size(int, int) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XMoveWindow”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::event_handler() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
dlib::base_window::set_pos(long, long) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XwcLookupString”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::event_handler() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XGetICValues”, referenced from:
dlib::base_window::base_window(bool, bool) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XLookupString”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::event_handler() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XDestroyWindow”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::event_handler() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
dlib::base_window::close_window() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XGetModifierMapping”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::init_keyboard_mod_masks() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XCreatePixmap”, referenced from:
void nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::vals_internal::create<unsigned int>(unsigned int*, int, bool, bool, bool, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type) in libdlib.a(fonts.o)
“_cblas_daxpy”, referenced from:
dlib::blas_bindings::cblas_axpy(int, double, double const*, int, double*, int) in libdlib.a(global_function_search.o)
“_XInitImage”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::event_handler() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XSetSelectionOwner”, referenced from:
dlib::put_on_clipboard(std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> > const&) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_dpbtrf_“, referenced from:
dlib::lapack::binding::pbtrf(char, int, int, double*, int) in libdlib.a(global_function_search.o)
“_XPutImage”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::event_handler() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XFreeGC”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::event_handler() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
void nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::vals_internal::create<unsigned int>(unsigned int*, int, bool, bool, bool, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type) in libdlib.a(fonts.o)
nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::vals_internal::~vals_internal() in libdlib.a(fonts.o)
“_XCreateIC”, referenced from:
dlib::base_window::base_window(bool, bool) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_cblas_ddot”, referenced from:
dlib::blas_bindings::cblas_dot(int, double const*, int, double const*, int) in libdlib.a(global_function_search.o)
“_XSetForeground”, referenced from:
void nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::vals_internal::create<unsigned int>(unsigned int*, int, bool, bool, bool, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type) in libdlib.a(fonts.o)
“_dpotrf_“, referenced from:
dlib::lapack::binding::potrf(char, int, double*, int) in libdlib.a(global_function_search.o)
“_XCreateGC”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::event_handler() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
void nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::vals_internal::create<unsigned int>(unsigned int*, int, bool, bool, bool, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type) in libdlib.a(fonts.o)
“_XFreePixmap”, referenced from:
void nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::vals_internal::create<unsigned int>(unsigned int*, int, bool, bool, bool, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type) in libdlib.a(fonts.o)
nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::vals_internal::~vals_internal() in libdlib.a(fonts.o)
“_XCreateWindow”, referenced from:
dlib::base_window::base_window(bool, bool) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::thread() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XPending”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::event_handler() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XFree”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::event_handler() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
dlib::get_from_clipboard(std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> >&) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
dlib::base_window::base_window(bool, bool) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
dlib::base_window::set_title(std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> > const&) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
dlib::base_window::set_size(int, int) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
dlib::base_window::set_im_pos(long, long) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::thread() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
...
“_cblas_dtrsm”, referenced from:
dlib::blas_bindings::cblas_trsm(dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_ORDER, dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_SIDE, dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_UPLO, dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_TRANSPOSE, dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_DIAG, int, int, double, double const*, int, double*, int) in libdlib.a(global_function_search.o)
“_XAllocSizeHints”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::event_handler() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
dlib::base_window::base_window(bool, bool) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
dlib::base_window::set_size(int, int) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XCheckIfEvent”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::event_handler() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_cblas_dgemv”, referenced from:
dlib::blas_bindings::cblas_gemv(dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_ORDER, dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_TRANSPOSE, int, int, double, double const*, int, double const*, int, double, double*, int) in libdlib.a(global_function_search.o)
“_cblas_saxpy”, referenced from:
dlib::blas_bindings::cblas_axpy(int, float, float const*, int, float*, int) in libdlib.a(cpu_dlib.o)
dlib::blas_bindings::cblas_axpy(int, float, float const*, int, float*, int) in libdlib.a(tensor_tools.o)
“_dgetrf_“, referenced from:
dlib::lapack::binding::getrf(int, int, double*, int, int*) in libdlib.a(global_function_search.o)
“_opendir$INODE64”, referenced from:
dlib::disable_if<dlib::is_std_vector<dlib::queue_kernel_2<dlib::directory, 20ul, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >, void>::type dlib::directory_helper_get_dirs<dlib::queue_kernel_2<dlib::directory, 20ul, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::directory::data const&, dlib::queue_kernel_2<dlib::directory, 20ul, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> >&) in libdlib.a(dir_nav_extensions.o)
dlib::disable_if<dlib::is_std_vector<dlib::queue_kernel_c<dlib::queue_kernel_1<dlib::directory, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > >, void>::type dlib::directory_helper_get_dirs<dlib::queue_kernel_c<dlib::queue_kernel_1<dlib::directory, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > >(dlib::directory::data const&, dlib::queue_kernel_c<dlib::queue_kernel_1<dlib::directory, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_

    1<char> > >&) in libdlib.a(widgets.o)
    dlib::disable_if<dlib::is_std_vector<dlib::queue_kernel_c<dlib::queue_kernel_1<dlib::file, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > >, void>::type dlib::directory_helper_get_files<dlib::queue_kernel_c<dlib::queue_kernel_1<dlib::file, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>

 > > >(dlib::directory::data const&, dlib::queue_kernel_c<dlib::queue_kernel_1<dlib::file, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >&) in libdlib.a(widgets.o)
“_XChangeProperty”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::event_handler() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XSetICValues”, referenced from:
dlib::base_window::set_im_pos(long, long) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XCreateFontSet”, referenced from:
dlib::base_window::base_window(bool, bool) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
void nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::vals_internal::create<unsigned int>(unsigned int*, int, bool, bool, bool, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type) in libdlib.a(fonts.o)
“_cblas_dscal”, referenced from:
dlib::blas_bindings::cblas_scal(int, double, double*) in libdlib.a(global_function_search.o)
“_XScreenNumberOfScreen”, referenced from:
dlib::base_window::get_display_size(unsigned long&, unsigned long&) const in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_cblas_sscal”, referenced from:
dlib::blas_bindings::cblas_scal(int, float, float*) in libdlib.a(cpu_dlib.o)
dlib::blas_bindings::cblas_scal(int, float, float*) in libdlib.a(tensor_tools.o)
“_XSendEvent”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::event_handler() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::~event_handler_thread() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XGetSelectionOwner”, referenced from:
dlib::get_from_clipboard(std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> >&) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XFlush”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::event_handler() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
dlib::base_window::set_title(std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> > const&) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
dlib::base_window::show() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
dlib::base_window::hide() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
dlib::base_window::set_size(int, int) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
dlib::base_window::set_pos(long, long) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
dlib::base_window::invalidate_rectangle(dlib::rectangle const&) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
...
“_cblas_dgemm”, referenced from:
dlib::blas_bindings::cblas_gemm(dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_ORDER, dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_TRANSPOSE, dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_TRANSPOSE, int, int, int, double, double const*, int, double const*, int, double, double*, int) in libdlib.a(global_function_search.o)
“_XFilterEvent”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::event_handler() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_XInternAtom”, referenced from:
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::event_handler() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
dlib::get_from_clipboard(std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> >&) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::thread() in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
“_sgetrf_“, referenced from:
dlib::lapack::binding::getrf(int, int, float*, int, int*) in libdlib.a(tensor_tools.o)
“_cblas_strsm”, referenced from:
dlib::blas_bindings::cblas_trsm(dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_ORDER, dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_SIDE, dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_UPLO, dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_TRANSPOSE, dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_DIAG, int, int, float, float const*, int, float*, int) in libdlib.a(tensor_tools.o)
“_readdir$INODE64", referenced from:
dlib::disable_if<dlib::is_std_vector<dlib::queue_kernel_2<dlib::directory, 20ul, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >, void>::type dlib::directory_helper_get_dirs<dlib::queue_kernel_2<dlib::directory, 20ul, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::directory::data const&, dlib::queue_kernel_2<dlib::directory, 20ul, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> >&) in libdlib.a(dir_nav_extensions.o)
dlib::disable_if<dlib::is_std_vector<dlib::queue_kernel_c<dlib::queue_kernel_1<dlib::directory, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > >, void>::type dlib::directory_helper_get_dirs<dlib::queue_kernel_c<dlib::queue_kernel_1<dlib::directory, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > >(dlib::directory::data const&, dlib::queue_kernel_c<dlib::queue_kernel_1<dlib::directory, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >&) in libdlib.a(widgets.o)
dlib::disable_if<dlib::is_std_vector<dlib::queue_kernel_c<dlib::queue_kernel_1<dlib::file, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > >, void>::type dlib::directory_helper_get_files<dlib::queue_kernel_c<dlib::queue_kernel_1<dlib::file, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > >(dlib::directory::data const&, dlib::queue_kernel_c<dlib::queue_kernel_1<dlib::file, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >&) in libdlib.a(widgets.o)
“_dsyevr_“, referenced from:
dlib::lapack::binding::syevr(char, char, char, int, double*, int, double, double, int, int, double, int*, double*, double*, int, int*, double*, int, int*, int) in libdlib.a(global_function_search.o)
“_XwcTextPropertyToTextList”, referenced from:
dlib::get_from_clipboard(std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> >&) in libdlib.a(gui_core_kernel_2.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: There should be some messages about X11 at configuration time (when you run `cmake -G Xcode ...`). Add them into the question post. Error `Undefined symbols` means that *linking* with X11 hadn't been performed. Setting variable `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH` doesn't help with linking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)